# How to check that the string contains (if) only allowed html tags?

Tags: groovy

Allowed tags are stored in the list. I need a simple validation method that returns false if the test string contains *any* "not allowed tags".

I need smthg better than

```
static final Pattern TAG_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?<=</?)([^ >/]+)")
static final ArrayList<String> allowedTags = ["p", "div", "b", "strong" ,"ul" ,"li", "span", "style", "a", "table", "tr", "th","td"]

static Boolean parseTag(String str){
    Matcher m = TAG_PATTERN.matcher(str);
    while(m.find()) {
        String tag = m.group(1);
        if (!allowedTags.contains(tag)){
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: please share your code related to that case. Don't ask before tried.

Comment: `String.contains(tag)` ? You have a list so iterate the list... Please see [ask]

Comment: i need to find any tags (if exists) NOT from list. Iterate what?

Comment: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Cleaner.html

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are dealing with possibly non-well-formed html, the [tagsoup parser](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup) might be an option as it can parse malformatted (i.e. "real" in the sense that a lot of the HTML source on the web is not well formed) html/xml source.

The following code uses tagsoup and the groovy XmlSlurper to parse input and validate against a list of valid tag names:

```
@Grab('org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup:tagsoup:1.2.1')
import org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser

def html = '''
<html>
  <body>
    <span>some content</span>
  </body>
  <not-allowed>some content</not-allowed>
</html>
'''

def document = new XmlSlurper(new Parser()).parseText(html)
def validTags = ['html', 'body', 'span']

def isValid = document.'**'.every { tag ->
  println "${tag.name()} is ${tag.name()?.toLowerCase() in validTags ? '' : 'not '} allowed"
  tag.name()?.toLowerCase() in validTags
}

println "\nVALID: $isValid"
```

produces:

```
html is  allowed
body is  allowed
span is  allowed
not-allowed is not  allowed

VALID: false
```

The code uses [XmlSlurper](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_parsing_xml) from the groovy libraries. The `**` operator does a [depth first](http://groovy-lang.org/processing-xml.html#_speed_things_up_with_breadthfirst_and_depthfirst) search through all tags in the xml structure and the `every` call will return false if any of the `tag.name()?.toLowerCase() in validTags` expressions return false.

**edit**: assuming you have well formed html, you can still use the above and just replace the parse line with:

```
def document = new XmlSlurper().parseText(html)
```

and leave out the `@Grab` and `import` directives at the top of the script.